# window.location.assign() navigate to user input of url?

Tags: javascript, forms, user-input, assign, window.location

I need to use Javascript `window.location.assign()` to take input from a user in an inputbox and once a button is clicked the user will be taken to the URL they entered in that inputbox- I am having difficulty finding this online. I am assuming I would need to add a function to my script (not shown).

```
    <form style="padding-top: 20px;">
        URL: <input type="url" name="url">
        <input type="button" value="GO!" onclick="newUrl()">
    </form>
```

Comment: Retrospectively, navigating users to arbitrary client-side input is a security concern. Application logic (residing on either frontend or backend) should at least sanitize the input. (Best if a whitelist is used)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, instead of putting the function in "onclick" in the button, I suggest putting it on the form element's "onsubmit" handler. That way, a simple "Enter" key can also cause the navigation.

Second, since we're putting the callback on the form, the form's action should changed to 'javascript', like this:

```
<form style="padding-top 20px;" action="javascript://#" onsubmit="newUrl(this.elements['url'].value)">
    URL: <input type="text" name="url">
    <input type="submit" value="GO!">
</form>
```

I've put the url in the first parameter of the "newUrl" function, for ease of writing.

Finally, your "newUrl" function:

```
function newUrl(url) {
    window.location.assign(url);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, Danny. I had tried other options that didn't work, so I didn't want to include them in my code posted here! Appreciate you not downvoting me. Still new to all! Thanks again- you explained it perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

Before using the `window.location.assign` I would like you to read this

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location/assign

> The Location.assign() method causes the window to load and display the
>   document at the URL specified.
>
> If the assignment can't happen because of a security violation, a
>   DOMException of the SECURITY_ERROR type is thrown. This happens if the
>   origin of the script calling the method is different from the origin
>   of the page originally described by the Location object, mostly when
>   the script is hosted on a different domain.
>
> If the provided URL is not valid, a DOMException of the SYNTAX_ERROR
>   type is thrown.

Here is the what you can do to use it

```js
function newUrl(){
  window.location.assign(document.getElementById("url").value);
}
```

```html
 <form style="padding-top: 20px;">
        URL: <input type="url" name="url" id="url">
        <input type="button" value="GO!" onclick="newUrl()">
    </form>
```

Comment: This works great! Thanks for helping out. Now that I see it, it seems really simple.

Answer (score 0):

Simple alternative

```html
<form style="padding-top 20px;" onsubmit="this.action=document.getElementById('url').value">
  URL: <input type="text" id="url">
  <input type="submit" value="GO!">
</form>
```